# How to move up layout when show soft key board

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Im have problem with login page. in wanna layout move up when touch input data in Edittext.
 Im try many way but it not working.  Who can help me reslove it? .really i dont know how to code it work. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add this in your java:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

or this in your activity in Manifest.xml

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> 
</activity>
```